# TikZ: use-provide UML-style

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw some components diagrams with use and provide ports with TikZ. But the way I want them to look is quite different from what tikz-uml since my needs are differents. I do not focus on describing a real application, but more on the structure between components.

There are mainly two cases: those that I know how verbose I want the code to be, and those I'm not sure about the way to express them.

Here are the simple cases.

- When the components are close enough the U and the circle should touch.

  [image: Close components.]

  And the code should be as simple as this.

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[component] (A) {A};
      \node[component,right of=A] (B) {B};
      \draw[useprovide] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```
- But when the components are too far away, the port stay within 1cm of the border of the component and the ports are connected with a line.

  [image: Far components.]

  And the code should remain exactly the same.
- Also, two components may be connected by more than one pair of ports and they should be placed nicely.

  [image: Multiple use-provide between two components.]

  And the code should remain as simple as possible. For instance:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[component] (A) {A};
      \node[component,above of=A] (B) {B};
      \draw[useprovide] (A) -- (B);
      \draw[useprovide] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

  Optionally it would be nice if it would allow me to put some text on the lines and around the use and provide ports.

  And here are the cases I also need to draw but I don't know how I want to write them.
- One "use" port for several "provide" ports.

  [image: Multiple use.]

  Notice the small separation between the lines on the "use" side while they still touch the half circle.
- One "provide" port for multiple "use" ports.

  [image: Multiple provide.]

  Again, there is a small gap between the lines.
- And last but not least, when the components are far away in a complex setting, I may want to decide of the path of the line connecting them, but let the code put the use and provide shapes at the right place.

  [image: Complex connection path.]

  Notice How the long connection between A and D is made of 3 parts. I may also want the 90° turn on the side of D to happen before the use port. (But I'll probably try to avoid that.)

The question is: how can I do that easily? Should I use a `decorated path`? Arrow tips? Something completely different? For a given method, how do I handle those 6 cases?

The code of the examples above is ugly and full of little adjustments.

What I tried:

- I tried to define the U shape as a new node shape. I basically copied the `semi circle` predefined node shape code and modified it to put it in the right direction and offset it a bit so that the path it terminates just touch it. But the fact that it is part of the PGF layer make it hard to use. I especially don't understand how the transformations (translations and rotations) work.
- I tried with a `to path` operation but things get complicated as soon as I want to handle the second case as there is no facility like the state precondition of the path length as there is for the `decorated path`. The automatic corrdinate transformation of the `decorated path` (that makes the path drawing always straight on the right) is also absent from the `to path` operation and forces me to work in 2D instead of 1D. In addition to this, it draws my half circle backward sometimes for no apparent reason.

I am open to any other solution as long as it makes me write as little "noise" code as possible for each schema.

I can provide the code of my failed attempts if needed, as well as the code I used for the schema here.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what's your question. Do you want somebody develops a package for such diagrams?

Comment: @Ignasi here it is, I clarified the question and the things I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Next code shows you a possible solution. Instead of new shapes or decorations I propose some `.style` which will add U or circles to regular nodes. I've preferred to use this solution instead of `pics` because It's not so easy to place last ones.

All `component` boxes are defined with

```
component/.style={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.5cm, fill=green}
```

while `u` and `o` additions are based in two `circle` nodes

```
u/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=7mm,outer sep=0pt},
o/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=6mm,outer sep=0pt}
```

The `o-arm` is just a line with a circular node attached to it:

```
owest/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
    \pgfextra 
    \draw ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.west)--++(180:6.5mm) 
        node[o,anchor=east] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
    \endpgfextra}},
owest/.default={0mm}{owest},
```

and the `u-arm` is also a line with a circular node, but clipped to its half:

```
ueast/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
    \pgfextra 
    \begin{scope}  
        \clip ([yshift={#1+4mm}]\tikzlastnode.east) rectangle ++(1cm,-8mm); 
        \draw ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.east)--++(0:6.5mm) 
            node[u,anchor=west] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
    \end {scope} 
    \endpgfextra}},
ueast/.default={0mm}{ueast},
```

As you can see both styles have two arguments, the first one is a x/y-shift around the main anchor (north, west, south, east) and the second a name sufix. Both arguments will help to draw double connections between component. By default their values are 0mm shift and suffix {u|o}{north|east|south|west}.

Both `u` and `o` components are circular nodes instead of just circles because this way it's easier to draw paths to any of their positions like in your last three examples.

As you can see all dimensions are fixed, but you can change according your taste. With the code provided, `u-arm` is 1cm long, `o-arm` is 1.25cm long and distance between nodes should be 2cm to simulate attaching both. May be you'll have to take care with these values in case you change `line width`.

[image]

```
\node[component,ueast,onorth] (A) {A};
\node[component, right=2cm of A, owest,unorth] (B) {B};
\draw[|<->|,red] ([yshift=-3mm]A.north east)--++(0:2cm) node[above,midway]{\SI{2}{\centi\meter}};
\draw[|<->|,red] ([xshift=5mm]B.north)--++(90:{1cm}) node[right,midway]{\SI{1}{\centi\meter}};
\draw[|<->|,red] ([xshift=-5mm]A.north)--node[left]{\SI{1.25}{\centi\meter}} ++(90:{1.25cm});
```

When `component` nodes are separated, you can `draw` lines between any positions of their `u` or `o` nodes.

Be careful. You can use something like `B-owest` when referring to a `o-arm` node because `B-owest` really means "draw until `B-owest.center` and stop at its border", but it you use this expression with an `u-arm`, the same will happen. The blue line in next example shows it. Next code shows how to solve this problem using explicit border anchor points, like `A-ueast.west` or `B-owest.130`. The last one is an anchor at angle 130 over nodes border and the first is an alias for `A-ueast.180`.

```
\node[component,ueast] (A) {A};
\node[component, right=5cm of A, owest] (B) {B};
\draw (A-ueast.west)--(B-owest);
\draw[red] (A-ueast.170)--(B-owest.130);
\draw[red] (A-ueast.-120)--(B-owest.south);
```

[image]

With this syntax it's easy to get joints like in third example:

[image]

[image]

When you have to draw more than one connection in same component side you can use the corresponding style, but providing corresponding arguments. Something like:

```
\node[component,onorth={-5mm}{-5},onorth={5mm}{5}] (A) {A};
\node[component, above=2cm of A,usouth={-5mm}{-5},usouth={5mm}{5}] (B) {B};
```

[image]

or

```
\node[component,oeast={-4mm}{-4},ueast={4mm}{4}] (A) {A};
\node[component,right=4cm of A,uwest={-4mm}{-4},owest={4mm}{4}] (B) {B};
\draw (A--4)--(B--4.east);
\draw (A-4.west)--(B-4);
```

[image]

That's all. Now the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    component/.style={draw, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.5cm, fill=green},
    u/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=7mm,outer sep=0pt},
    o/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=6mm,outer sep=0pt},
    ueast/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \begin{scope}  
            \clip ([yshift={#1+4mm}]\tikzlastnode.east) rectangle ++(1cm,-8mm); 
            \draw ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.east)--++(0:6.5mm) 
                node[u,anchor=west] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \end {scope} 
        \endpgfextra}},
    ueast/.default={0mm}{ueast},
    uwest/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \begin{scope} 
            \clip ([yshift={#1+4mm}]\tikzlastnode.west) rectangle ++(-1cm,-8mm); 
            \draw ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.west)--++(180:6.5mm)  
                node[u,anchor=east] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \end {scope} 
        \endpgfextra}},
    uwest/.default={0mm}{uwest},
    unorth/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \begin{scope} 
            \clip ([xshift={#1+4mm}]\tikzlastnode.north) rectangle ++(-8mm,1cm); 
            \draw ([xshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.north)--++(90:6.5mm)  
                node[u,anchor=south] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {};
         \end {scope} 
         \endpgfextra}},
    unorth/.default={0mm}{unorth},
    usouth/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \begin{scope}  
            \clip ([xshift={#1+4mm}]\tikzlastnode.south) rectangle ++(-8mm,-1cm); 
            \draw ([xshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.south)--++(-90:6.5mm)  
                node[u,anchor=north] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \end {scope} 
        \endpgfextra}},
    usouth/.default={0mm}{usouth},
    oeast/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \draw ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.east)--++(0:6.5mm) 
            node[o,anchor=west] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \endpgfextra}},
    oeast/.default={0mm}{oeast},
    owest/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \draw ([yshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.west)--++(180:6.5mm) 
            node[o,anchor=east] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \endpgfextra}},
    owest/.default={0mm}{owest},
    onorth/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \draw ([xshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.north)--++(90:6.5mm) 
            node[o,anchor=south] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \endpgfextra}},
    onorth/.default={0mm}{onorth},
    osouth/.style 2 args={append after command={ 
        \pgfextra 
        \draw ([xshift=#1]\tikzlastnode.south)--++(-90:6.5mm) 
            node[o,anchor=north] (\tikzlastnode-#2) {}; 
        \endpgfextra}},
    osouth/.default={0mm}{osouth},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[component,ueast,onorth] (A) {A};
\node[component, right=2cm of A, owest,unorth] (B) {B};
\draw[|<->|,red] ([yshift=-3mm]A.north east)--++(0:2cm) node[above,midway]{\SI{2}{\centi\meter}};
\draw[|<->|,red] ([xshift=5mm]B.north)--++(90:{1cm}) node[right,midway]{\SI{1}{\centi\meter}};
\draw[|<->|,red] ([xshift=-5mm]A.north)--node[left]{\SI{1.25}{\centi\meter}} ++(90:{1.25cm});
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[component,ueast] (A) {A};
\node[component, right=5cm of A, owest] (B) {B};
\draw[line width=1mm, blue, opacity=.5] (A-ueast)--(B-owest);
\draw (A-ueast.west)--(B-owest);
\draw[red] (A-ueast.170)--(B-owest.130);
\draw[red] (A-ueast.-120)--(B-owest.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[component,unorth] (A) {A};
\node[component, above right=3cm and -5mm of A, osouth] (C) {C};
\node[component, above left=3cm and -5mm of A, osouth] (B) {B};
\draw (A-unorth.-85)|-(C-osouth);
\draw (A-unorth.-95)|-(B-osouth);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[component,onorth={-5mm}{-5},onorth={5mm}{5}] (A) {A};
\node[component, above=2cm of A,usouth={-5mm}{-5},usouth={5mm}{5}] (B) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[component,oeast={-4mm}{-4},ueast={4mm}{4}] (A) {A};
\node[component,right=4cm of A,uwest={-4mm}{-4},owest={4mm}{4}] (B) {B};
\draw (A--4)--(B--4.east);
\draw (A-4.west)--(B-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is better than the arrow tips + *decorated path* I was trying to use. I didn't know that `A.-85` notation. Is that an angle? So with this solution, if I want the U and circle to *almost touch* like in the first case, I have to separate them by exactly 2cm?

Comment: In order to draw several ports on the same side, I make a `\path` between the wanted corners and put empty nodes with style `unorth` that are positioned on the path with option `/tikz/pos`. Am I right?

Comment: Not a big deal, but it seems like the presence of a `scope` environment prevent the path the node belong to from being drawn. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: @Celelibi I completely rewrite the answer. I hope it solves your doubts now. If it's still not enough, please insist.

Comment: sorry I took so much time to reply. (I had plenty of stuff to do with my PhD manuscript.) Your answer is just awesome. If you had an idea to make it easy to have several port shapes (square + half square, triangle + half triangle), that would be perfect.

Comment: @Celelibi: For square it's easy, copy `u` and `o` styles with another name and replace `circle` by `rectangle`. For triangles I'd suggest adding `geometric.shapes` library and using a 3 sides `regular polygon`. It won't be so easy, but make new questions and I'll try to help you.

Comment: that's what I currently did. But it's a lot of copy-paste. I would also like to add an argument for the length of the segments between the component and the port. (Large figures are either too wide or unreadable.) So having less code to modify / maintain would be better.

Comment: @Celelibi I'd suggest to open a follow up question with reference to this one. More people will see it and more people can help.

Comment: @Celelibi If you can make `u` and `o` styles variable with a parameter which defines their form (circle, rectangle, triangle, ...) as all other comands are based on them, there won't be no need for so much copy and paste. You can also ask how to add a length parameter.